# Problem to scan through every character in java

Tags: java, for-loop, token

so I'm doing a token scanner that scans through a text file and identifies each of the tokens in that text file to either it is identifier or number or symbol. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

//Create a pattern to see if it matches the string
String IDENTIFIER = "([a-z]|[A-Z])([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*";
String SYMBOL = "\\*|\\+|\\(|\\)|\\/|\\-";
String NUMBER = "\\d+";

//Scan the text input file
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

while(input.hasNext()){
  String token = input.nextLine();
  String ip[] = token.split("\\s+");
  System.out.println("Line: " + token);

  for(int i = 0 ; i< ip.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <ip[i].length(); j++){
      if(ip[i].substring(0,ip[i].length()).matches(IDENTIFIER)){
            System.out.println(ip[i] + " : IDENTIFIER");
      }else if(ip[i].substring(0,ip[i].length()).matches(NUMBER)){
            System.out.println(ip[i]+ " : NUMBER");
      }else if(ip[i].substring(0,ip[i].length()).matches(SYMBOL)){
            System.out.println(ip[i] + " : SYMBOL");
      }else 
            System.out.println("ERROR READING" + "'" + ip[i] + "'");
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

On the double for loop, the outer one scans through every single element in the array and the inner one scans through every single character of the element in the array. But it doesn't seem to work. Let's say the input file is:
34 + 89& - x * y23 / 56n34

the output I got is:
Line: 34 + 89& - x * y23 / 56n34
34 : NUMBER
34 : NUMBER

- : SYMBOL
  ERROR READING'89&'
  ERROR READING'89&'
  ERROR READING'89&'

- : SYMBOL
  x : IDENTIFIER

- : SYMBOL
  y23 : IDENTIFIER
  y23 : IDENTIFIER
  y23 : IDENTIFIER
  / : SYMBOL
  ERROR READING'56n34'
  ERROR READING'56n34'
  ERROR READING'56n34'
  ERROR READING'56n34'
  ERROR READING'56n34'

the out put that I expected:
Line: 34 + 89& - x * y23 / 56n34
34 : NUMBER

- : SYMBOL
  89: NUMBER
  ERROR READING'&'

- : SYMBOL
  x : IDENTIFIER

- : SYMBOL
  y23 : IDENTIFIER
  / : SYMBOL
  56: NUMBER
  n34: IDENTIFIER

Anyone knows what is the problem what my for loop. Thanks

Comment: The variable j is not used inside the loop. What is the inner loop for?

Comment: as I mentioned, the inner loop is for scanning every character in ip[i]: For ex, in this case: ip[0] would be 34. The inner loop will scan through 34 from j to the length of it which is 2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative approach might be close to doing the job.

For working character-by-character, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

The Unicode Consortium has identified over 140,000 characters across various languages, plus symbols and emojis. To each of these the Consortium has permanently assigned a specific number as an identifier. That number is known as a *code point*.

Avoid `char` and its wrapper class `Character` to represent individual characters. The `char` type in Java is legacy, essentially broken, unable to represent most characters.

```java
package work.basil.text;

public class App6
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App6 app = new App6();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ()
    {
        String input = "A1+";
        input.codePoints().forEach(
                App6 :: report
        );
    }

    public static void report ( int codePoint )
    {
        if ( Character.isJavaIdentifierPart( codePoint ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "Java Identifier part: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) );
        } else if ( Character.isDigit( codePoint ) )
        {
            System.out.println( "Digit: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) );
        } else if ( Character.getType( codePoint ) == Character.MATH_SYMBOL )
        {
            System.out.println( "Math symbol: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "Something else: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) + " (code point " + codePoint + ")." );
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Java Identifier part: A
Java Identifier part: 1
Something else:  (code point 128567).
Math symbol: +
```

Comment: Sr, I'm a little bit unsure about t the int code point. Can you explain what it is. Thanks

Comment: @Yang Did you read the Wikipedia page to which I linked? I will add a summary to the Answer.

Comment: Thanks, I read it but is there any way to check whether it matches a specific regex since the JavaIdentifierPart and Math symbol are all built in library for java which don't include all of the symbol I want to to check

Comment: @Yang I am not a fan of regex. To define your own set of characters to use in checking, make an array of `int` or a `List` (or [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html)) of `Integer` objects. Populate with the code point of each character you want to target. Search that array/list/set for a match.